# What does the term "recruitment of T-cell" mean?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology, immune-system

With respect to the [article](http://jem.rupress.org/content/189/10/1591/tab-pdf), what does the term "recruitment of T-cell" mean? Who recruits T- cell? Does recruiting T-cell mean the T-cells get a sense of directionality to get activated by the APC's?

Comment: Read into MHC-class molecules, and how they're processed. You have Wiki for that, but if you're interested in the evolutionary mechanisms that are very importantly in play in our modern times, check out this Biostars tutorial: https://www.biostars.org/p/5817/#95075 for some nice explanations and software examples, @CMosychuk (also relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting it properly, it's the adaptive response that's recruiting the T cell, evidenced by the last line in their abstract:

"Therefore, the contribution of a T cell clone to the immune response is mostly determined by the time of its entry into the immune repertoire, i.e., the time of first cell division after antigen encounter."

It's strange because when i think of recruiting a T cell it's always to the tissue or site of infection or what have you.